# CasperJS each then next (future) value of response array

Tags: javascript, arrays, phantomjs, casperjs

im using eachThen() method of CasperJS and I need to know the value of the next iteration item.

I have items like this :

```
array = [

[22,"blah"],
[22,"blah"],
[23,"blah"],
[24,"blah"],
[24,"blah"],
[24,"blah"]
]
```

I'm generating one file per group of items (grouped by [0]) .

My first approach was to compare the actual item with the previous item at the beginning of the iteration , and if [0] is different generate the file, like this :

```
//previousItem was initilizated = to actualItem

   casper.eachThen(array , function (response) {
            var actualItem = response.data

        casper.then(function(){
            if(actualItem[0] != previousItem[0]){
                var filename = previousItem[0]+"file.html"
                var f = fs.open(filename, 'a');
                f.write(stdFile);
                f.close();  
                previous = actualItem
            }
        });

//operations that prepares stdFile to be created
```

Problem appears at the end of the cycle, as im comparing actual with previous, the last group will not generate any files (of course, the 2 last items will have the same [0], and after that the cycle will end)

My solution here is to ask for the next item instead of the previous, and generate the file **at the end** of each iteration , but I dont know how to tell Casper to give me the item of actualItem+1 in the array.

I will try to fix this iterating the same array inside in paralel and returning the value of actual+1 , but maybe there is a way to do it using response variable.

The result must be 3 files : 22file.html , 23file.html and 24file.html
There are a lot of requests to make

, so I need to win any second I can.

If you have another approach to achieve this please let me know.

PS: Sorry for my english, its not my native language

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a bigger part of your code? You comment *"//previousItem was initilizated = to actualItem"* doesn't make sense, because `actualItem` is not yet defined at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first approach was too complicated, probably because I didnt sleep so much these days.

This is what I did :

```
cajIndex = 0;

//this block generates the file if actualItem (or actualCajero is the same) is not undefined  and the actualItem[0] is not the same as the next item 

if (actualCajero != undefined)
        {
            if (actualCajero[0] != cajerosArray[cajIndex][0]){
                casper.then(function(){

                    var filename = "Ventas local"+" "+nombreLocal+"_"+actualDay[1]+"-"+actualDay[2]
                    stdFile = '<h1>'+filename+'</h1> <table border="1">'+ stdTable + '</table>';
                    this.echo("generando archivo "+filename);
                    var f = fs.open(filename+".xls", 'a');
                    f.write(stdFile);
                    f.close();  
                    stdTable = "";
                    stdFile = "";

                });
            }
        }

//after this i do my operations , ask again for file creating at the end but now if the next item is undefined, if it is undefined creates the file then

cajIndex++
```

and that solves everything, the key was declaring that index at 0 and asking for file creating before assigning actualItem to response, and then ask again at the end for the last item.

Hope it helps